# Grails - Exception inside withTransaction block not working

Tags: grails

I am throwing a custom exception inside the withTransaction method based on a scenarion when author not found.But the issue I am facing is even if the code is enetering inside the exception block for non existent authors, it is not existing out of the flow but continuing with the flow.
Just wanted to check is there anything i am missing here or doing wrong.

```
Author.withTransaction() {
authStatus -> def author = Author.get(id)
if (!author) { 
log.warn "author not found" 
throw new NotFoundException('author not found') 
}
author.status = 'completed'
author.save()
}
```

Thanks
Sam

Comment: So "author not found" is written to your log, but it still tries to set the status of a null object? Your code looks fine.

Comment: yes..it still proceeding with the next set of code which is `author.status = 'completed' ,author.save()`.

Comment: So just to be 100% sure, you see both the "author not found" in your log, and it throws an NullPointerException because it cannot set the status? If that's the case you should try cleaning the project and rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

do you really have `authStatus -> def author = Author.get(id)` all on one line ? or is `authStatus ->` on `withTransaction` line, usually a `return` stops something from continuing  but since you are throwing there shouldn't be a need for that. Why not reverse that logic to

```
if (author) {
  do something
  return
}
//obviously we didn't have an author since we haven't returned so back to your throw 
log.warn "author not found" 
throw new NotFoundException('author not found')
```

I would change that to

```
Author.withTransaction {

def author = Author.get(id)
if (author) { 
 author.status = 'completed'
 author.save()
 return author
}
log.warn "author not found" 
throw new NotFoundException('author not found') 
}
```

Personally I would probably wrap entire thing around try catch and not even throw that specific case but instead try to capture get and save errors with one throw at bottom of try catch since you may have got the record but did you manage to save it correctly ?

Comment: There is no reason why this code should work different than the one from the question. Its only less readable and less clean, if you don't have the author its an exceptional state which should be handled in the if statement, not in the "normal" flow

Comment: @TomasBartalos not disputing that, my point was really to try it from all angles to see if there is a difference in behaviour. This is how a problem is nipped before it becomes a question on SO. Try it from all angles and understand the behaviour.